# dcast multiple columns independently

Tags: r, data.table

Can this be done in one line?  The example is for two variables however I'd like to use it for more, which makes this approach cumbersome.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

a <- dcast(mpg, year ~ cyl, fun=length, value.var = "cyl")
b <- dcast(mpg, year ~ class, fun=length, value.var = "class")
c <- inner_join(a, b, by = "year")

> c
  year  4 5  6  8 2seater compact midsize minivan pickup subcompact suv
1 1999 45 0 45 27       2      25      20       6     16         19  29
2 2008 36 4 34 43       3      22      21       5     17         16  33
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we use `data.table`, then `melt`  first and use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mpg[c('year', 'cyl', 'class')]), 
        id.var = 'year'), year ~ value)
```

A version with chaining of `[]` would look like:

```
mpg = as.data.table(mpg[c('year', 'cyl', 'class')])
mpg[ , melt(.SD, id.var = 'year')
    ][ , dcast(.SD, year ~ value, fun.aggregate=length)]
```

---

Or use `recast` from `reshape2` (one-liner)

```
library(reshape2)
recast(mpg[c('year', 'cyl', 'class')], id.var = 'year', year ~ value)
#  year 2seater  4 5  6  8 compact midsize minivan pickup subcompact suv
#1 1999       2 45 0 45 27      25      20       6     16         19  29
#2 2008       3 36 4 34 43      22      21       5     17         16  33
```

NOTE: The columns 'cyl', 'class' have different 'type'.  But, as we are only looking for the `length` it is ok

Answer (score 2):

I found a rather simple yet very flexible solution using `table`:

```
(do.call(cbind, lapply(list("cyl", "class"), function(x) {
  table(mpg[, c("year", x)])
})))
      4 5  6  8 2seater compact midsize minivan pickup subcompact suv
1999 45 0 45 27       2      25      20       6     16         19  29
2008 36 4 34 43       3      22      21       5     17         16  33
```

For more variables just add them to the list.

```
(do.call(cbind, lapply(list("cyl", "class", "drv"), function(x) {
  table(mpg[, c("year", x)])
})))
      4 5  6  8 2seater compact midsize minivan pickup subcompact suv  4  f  r
1999 45 0 45 27       2      25      20       6     16         19  29 49 57 11
2008 36 4 34 43       3      22      21       5     17         16  33 54 49 14
```