# Apply dcast multiple times for different variables

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

Suppose I have a data frame with id `A` and a couple of factor variables.

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.table(
  A =  as.factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D","E")),
  V1 = as.factor(c("x", "x", "y", "x", "y")),
  V2 = as.factor(c("u", "v", "w", "v", "u"))
)
```

In a real example, there can be more columns (say 1000) and the dataset has a couple of million rows, so I really care about performance.

I want to convert it into the following data.frame:

```
  A V1_x V1_y V2_u V2_v V2_w
1 A    1    0    1    0    0
2 B    1    0    0    1    0
3 C    0    1    0    0    1
4 D    1    0    0    1    0
5 E    0    1    1    0    0
```

**What would be the efficient method to implement this conversion?**

The way I do it right now is to apply dcast multiple times for each column separately. And rename columns accordingly.

```r
f <- function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0)
mydf2 =
  mydf %>%
  dcast(... ~ V1, fun.aggregate = f, value.var = "V1") %>%
  dcast(... ~ V2, fun.aggregate = f, value.var = "V2") 
  
colnames(mydf2) = c("A", "V1_x", "V1_y", "V2_u",  "V2_v",  "V2_w")
```

That does not seem efficient for many variables if we run it in a loop. In addition, renaming the variables at each step is not very robust if the number of factors varies from variable to variable.

Loop version for the same solution:

```r
mydf2 = mydf
for(tmp_var in  c("V1","V2")){
  ncol_before = ncol(mydf2)
  mydf2 =
    mydf2 %>%
    dcast( as.formula( sprintf("... ~ %s", tmp_var)  ),
          fun.aggregate = f, value.var = tmp_var)
  ncol_after = ncol(mydf2)
  # assign correct names to created vars
  colnames(mydf2)[ncol_before:ncol_after ] = paste0(tmp_var, "_", colnames(mydf2)[ncol_before:ncol_after ])
}
mydf2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(mydf, 'V1', type = 'character', fill = '0') %>%
      cSplit_e('V2', type = 'character', fill = '0')
#   A V1 V2 V1_x V1_y V2_u V2_v V2_w
#1: A  x  u    1    0    1    0    0
#2: B  x  v    1    0    0    1    0
#3: C  y  w    0    1    0    0    1
#4: D  x  v    1    0    0    1    0
#5: E  y  u    0    1    1    0    0
```

---

Or with `table` from `base R`

```
 do.call(cbind, lapply(2:3, function(i) table(mydf$A, mydf[[i]])))
```

---

Or the same approach in `data.table` syntax

```
nm1 <- names(mydf)[-1]
out <- mydf[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         as.data.frame.matrix(table(A, x))), .SDcols = nm1]
mydf[, names(out) := out][]
#   A V1 V2 V1.x V1.y V2.u V2.v V2.w
#1: A  x  u    1    0    1    0    0
#2: B  x  v    1    0    0    1    0
#3: C  y  w    0    1    0    0    1
#4: D  x  v    1    0    0    1    0
#5: E  y  u    0    1    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the data in long format, combine column name and column value, create a dummy column and get the data in wide format.

Using `tidyverse` this can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('V')) %>%
  unite(name, name, value) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
#   A      V1_x  V2_u  V2_v  V1_y  V2_w
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1     1     0     0     0
#2 B         1     0     1     0     0
#3 C         0     0     0     1     1
#4 D         1     0     1     0     0
#5 E         0     1     0     1     0
```

If you want to do this in `data.table` following the same logic you can try :

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- melt(setDT(mydf), id.vars = 'A')
df1[, c('variable', 'value') := .(paste(variable, value, sep = "_"), 1)]
dcast(df1, A~variable, value.var = 'value', fill = 0)
```

Comment: also a very elegant solution. Many, thanks. Actually performance on the big data is even better then what's reported before using data.table approach `Time difference of 9.892609 secs`

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to akrun for the solution. It's way more efficient than anything I saw before.

A quick follow up on the performance. Define the dataset with 200 columns and 100,000 observations.

```r
N = 1e5
mydf <- data.table(A =  1:N)
for(j in 1:100)
  mydf[[paste0("V",j)]] = sample(c("x", "y", "z"),N, replace = T)
for(j in 101:200)
  mydf[[paste0("V",j)]] = sample(c("v", "u", "w"),N, replace = T)
```

Then performance of data.table way:

```r
start_time <- Sys.time()
nm1 <- names(mydf)[-1]
out <- mydf[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) as.data.frame.matrix(table(A, x))), .SDcols = nm1]
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

`Time difference of 16.39327 secs`

```r
out[1:10,1:10]
    V1.x V1.y V1.z V2.x V2.y V2.z V3.x V3.y V3.z V4.x
 1:    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
 2:    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
 3:    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
 4:    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
 5:    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
 6:    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
 7:    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
 8:    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
 9:    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
10:    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
```

Performance of do.call is basically the same, but we still need to rename columns:

```r
start_time <- Sys.time()
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(2:201, function(i) table(mydf$A, mydf[[i]]) ))
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

`Time difference of 14.72284 secs`

```r
out[1:10,1:10]

   x y z x y z x y z x
1  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
2  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
3  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
4  0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
5  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
6  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
7  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
8  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
9  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
10 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

EDIT

Alternative, tidyverse solution by Ronak Shah is even more efficient on the data:

```r
start_time <- Sys.time()
mydf2 =
  mydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('V')) %>%
  unite(name, name, value) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fill = 0)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

`Time difference of 9.892609 secs`

```r
# A tibble: 100,000 x 601
       A  V1_z  V2_y  V3_y  V4_y  V5_z  V6_y  V7_y  V8_y  V9_x V10_z V11_x V12_y
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
 3     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     4     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5     5     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1
 6     6     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 7     7     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 8     8     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 9     9     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
10    10     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
# … with 99,990 more rows, and 588 more variables: V13_x <dbl>, V14_x <dbl>,
#   V15_z <dbl>, V16_z <dbl>, V17_y <dbl>, V18_y <dbl>, V19_z <dbl>,
#   V20_x <dbl>, V21_y <dbl>, V22_z <dbl>, V23_z <dbl>, V24_x <dbl>,
#   V25_y <dbl>, V26_z <dbl>, V27_z <dbl>, V28_x <dbl>, V29_z <dbl>,
#   V30_y <dbl>, V31_x <dbl>, V32_y <dbl>, V33_x <dbl>, V34_y <dbl>,
#   V35_y <dbl>, V36_y <dbl>, V37_x <dbl>, V38_y <dbl>, V39_y <dbl>,
#   V40_x <dbl>, V41_y <dbl>, V42_z <dbl>, V43_z <dbl>, V44_y <dbl>,
#   V45_x <dbl>, V46_x <dbl>, V47_x <dbl>, V48_y <dbl>, V49_y <dbl>,
#   V50_z <dbl>, V51_z <dbl>, V52_z <dbl>, V53_z <dbl>, V54_y <dbl>,
#   V55_y <dbl>, V56_y <dbl>, V57_x <dbl>, V58_x <dbl>, V59_x <dbl>,
#   V60_z <dbl>, V61_y <dbl>, V62_x <dbl>, V63_y <dbl>, V64_y <dbl>,
#   V65_y <dbl>, V66_x <dbl>, V67_x <dbl>, V68_x <dbl>, V69_y <dbl>,
#   V70_x <dbl>, V71_y <dbl>, V72_y <dbl>, V73_x <dbl>, V74_y <dbl>,
#   V75_x <dbl>, V76_z <dbl>, V77_x <dbl>, V78_y <dbl>, V79_z <dbl>,
#   V80_z <dbl>, V81_x <dbl>, V82_z <dbl>, V83_x <dbl>, V84_x <dbl>,
#   V85_z <dbl>, V86_z <dbl>, V87_x <dbl>, V88_z <dbl>, V89_x <dbl>,
#   V90_y <dbl>, V91_y <dbl>, V92_z <dbl>, V93_z <dbl>, V94_z <dbl>,
#   V95_z <dbl>, V96_z <dbl>, V97_z <dbl>, V98_y <dbl>, V99_z <dbl>,
#   V100_y <dbl>, V101_v <dbl>, V102_w <dbl>, V103_u <dbl>, V104_w <dbl>,
#   V105_v <dbl>, V106_v <dbl>, V107_u <dbl>, V108_w <dbl>, V109_v <dbl>,
#   V110_v <dbl>, V111_u <dbl>, V112_v <dbl>, …
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [dcast multiple columns independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343907/dcast-multiple-columns-independently), so applying the solution there:

```
dcast(melt(mydf, id.var = 'A'), A ~ variable + value, fun.aggregate = f)
```